# How to change a hidden_field array using Javascript without losing its correct format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails controller, I need an array direct_filter_params in a format like this (multi dimentional array, could have n elements):

```
direct_filter_params = [['gender','equals','male'], ['age','range',21,25]]
```

I am getting this from a form, having a hidden_field_tag :direct_filter_params:

```
<%= form_tag(user_demography__path, :method => :get, :remote => true) do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :direct_filter_params %>
<%= render :partial => "user_demography_filters" %>
<%= submit_tag "Find Users", :class => "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

I need to get the values into this from the form. I can get the values in the javascript file after the click() event fires, but the problem I am having is that Javascript/Jquery doesn't set the value in the proper format. I know it is confusing, so I will give a short example.

```
var a = [];
attribute = 'gender';
condition = 'equals';
value = 'Male';
var b = [attribute, condition, value];
$("direct_filter_params").val(b);
c=$("#direct_filter_params").val();
$("#direct_filter_params").val(c+b);
```

This sets the value of the element as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="direct_filter_params" id="direct_filter_params" value="gender,equals,Maleage,range,21,25">
```

Note the value is "gender,equals,Maleage,range,21,21". What I need is the value in the original format mentioned at the top. I have searched for hours, but I am unable to resolve this and am stuck at this small point despite all logic being complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var b = [attribute, condition, value],
    c = $("#direct_filter_params").val(),
    a = [b,c];
$("#direct_filter_params").val(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps partly. Now, I get the :direct_filter_params in the controller. But it is a string as follows:

"["gender","equals",["Female"]],["age","range",[21,25]]"

and if I try to convert it to an array using to_a method, it converts it into an array of characters. I am a bit rusty, but how do I get the arrays ["gender","equals",["Female"]] and ["age","range",[21,25]].

Please note that I have converted the last element of each array into an array itself as they are the arguments and can be one or many. It shouldn't affect any potential solution.

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(params[:direct_filter_params])` in your controller.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This solved my problem with a little modification. In the JS file, instead of using

a=[b,c];

separate them using a pipe as JSON.parse() will throw an error if it found ','

Split the param in controller using the '|' and then apply JSON.parse() to each of the string arrays. I will write the full code here if anyone wants it. Sorry for my bad formatting in comments - I am new to the site.